# MVC 4 send json object via POST Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am sending JSON objects from client but when I get my model all properties bind with default value.

I try some ways for example I got data as string but no results my expected.
So how can i solve this?

**Web API Config**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
    json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
    config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
}
```

**Model**

```
[Serializable]
public class WorkerPuantaj
{
    public int workT { get; set; }
    public int PDay { get; set; }
    public int PMonth { get; set; }
    public int PYear { get; set; }
    public int worker { get; set; }
}
```

**Client Request**

```
$.ajax({
       url: "/api/BuildingApi/AddPuantajItems",
       dataType: "json",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       type: 'POST',
       data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
       success: function (data) {
           alert("oldu");
       },
       error: function (a, b, c) {
           alert("olmadı");
       }
   });
```

**JSON Being Sent**

> "[{"workT":1,"PDay":20,"PMonth":4,"PYear":2014,"worker":3},{"workT":2,"PDay":21,‌​"PMonth":4,"PYear":2014,"worker":3},{"workT":3,"PDay":22,"PMonth":4,"PYear":2014,‌​"worker":3}]

[image: Debugger Display]

Comment: Right now it's impossible to answer this question.  What does the actual data that you're sending to the server look like?  What does your server-side method look like?

Comment: You can see in question so this i sent "[{"workT":1,"PDay":20,"PMonth":4,"PYear":2014,"worker":3},{"workT":2,"PDay":21,"PMonth":4,"PYear":2014,"worker":3},{"workT":3,"PDay":22,"PMonth":4,"PYear":2014,"worker":3}]"

Comment: I ran into a problem similar to this in deserializing JSON once. Try declaring the method argument for `AddPuantajItems` as `List<WorkerPuantaj>` instead of `WorkerPuantaj[]`.

Comment: Firstly thank you for edit my question.So it didn't change, same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are sending data as JSON array, in the method "AddPuantajItems" you should have your parameter as WorkerPuantaj[] but it is not the reason of the problem you have.

If you use Serializeable attribute on an MVC Web API model, it can't deserialize incoming JSON data into your model type. I don't know the reason but it fixed the issue for my test case.

Remove [Serializable] keyword and let me know if it has been fixed.